# Can I use ANTLR on C++ on XCode?

Tags: ios, antlr

I am wondering if I can use ANTLR on C++ on Xcode? If not, are there any alternatives?

I need production quality of the 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Also see: [Integrating ANTLR 4 in a C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913691/integrating-antlr-4-in-a-c-application)

ANTLR3 has a C target which you can use in a C++ project, albeit with a bit of hacking (no personal experience with that, I base it by reading the answers there).

> If not, are there any alternatives?

Sure, it's even been asked before: [C++ parser generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542276/c-parser-generator) which links to the [Wiki list of parser generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators), and of course, there's Google that has [more than one suggestion](https://www.google.com/search?q=parser+generator+c%2B%2B).