# Alternative to LLVM for C++ (bytecode generation)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, bison, lex, abstract-syntax-tree

I have written my lexer and parser in `flex` and `bison`. My project is based on C++ and I would love to stick to it. Currently my Interpreter is written in `C++` but I want to achieve faster execution time by converting to bytecode (some form of a VM-level bytecode) when my interpreter works. I know this can be achieved through `LLVM`. I had problems using it from a x64 OS and developing on a Visual Studio 2012 (32-bit). Some of which can be found @ [LLVM linker errors on VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785038/llvm-compilation-errors-on-vs-2012). The other tool I came across is `ANTLR` and if I understand correctly then the latest release does not easily integrate into `C++` yet. Many references were found for the same but a quick one can be @ [ANTLR integration with C++ issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913691/integrating-antlr-4-in-a-c-application). Also I do not want to dispose off my lexer and parser written in flex and bison. What are my options if I want to generate bytecode from my AST?

**EDIT:** My aim is to generate bytecode from my AST (for the target architecture) so the code can be executed at a Virtual Machine level. Currently I have an Interpretor which interpretes (executes the AST) based on C++ library and generates bytecode. I want to generate Bytecode straight from my AST and execute the AST in its bytecode.

Would be appreciated.

Comment: @jasal Thanks for the feedback. I have updated my question to indicate what I am looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating native bytecode **directly** from your AST is not possible (well actually it is, but that would be *extremely* difficult). You need some kind of intermediary step like emitting `LLVM` bytecode or code in some programming language of your choice. Please note that `LLVM` bytecode is **not the same as native target machine bytecode**. The `LLVM` bytecode has to be compiled to native binaries for target machines which is done by the respective frontend. So you could as well just generate C++ code from your AST using a handwritten code emitter which traverses your syntax tree. Then you use a C++ compiler for the target platform to compile it to the desired native binary.

Comment: thanks. As I mentioned in my question I ran into problems while trying to use LLVM. I understand that LLVM bytecode is not same as the native machine target but it provides for a VM. I am looking for some alternative to LLVM that can do the same for me.

Comment: I don't think that there is an alternative to `LLVM` that provides the functionality you are looking for. At least I've never heard of any.

Comment: Why not use C++ as _intermediate language_? You don't need `LLVM`'s VM functionality for generating native binaries anyway. Otherwise it would still be an interpreter which is just interpreting another representation of the same script code.

Comment: My current compiler uses C++11 as an intermediate language. I am a beginner in this field but from what I came across, I found LLVM can achieve much faster execution as it depends on the bytecode to be executed. As with my recent scenario I would like to use a tool of similar nature that boosts up my compiler.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. When you say you are using C++11 as intermediate language, does that mean that you are already __generating__ C++ from your AST (i.e. writing C++ code to a file) that you compile afterwards or does it mean that you use C++ for __interpreting__ the script?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am using C++ for interpreting the script.

Comment: There exist some other projects as alternatives to LLVM, but I don't know how maintained they are: this one for example: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/